# Which language preferable to write test cases using appium ?

Tags: appium

I have heard that we can write test cases in appium using java objective-c, javascript, python etc languages.

I am bit confused can somebody help me ? which language should  i used ?

Comment: Whichever you prefer to code in.

Comment: thats why i am asking , as we are having so much frameworks around it and they are language dependent

Answer (score 3):

I would go for java. You will get lots of solutions around that will boost your automation using appium.